# why does plt.scatter(['1','2','3'], [1, 2, 3]) show differently in matplotlib1.4.3 and matplotlib2.1.1

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following codes show different images in matplotlib 1.4.3 and matplotlib 2.1.1, and the former meets my expectation.

```
plt.scatter(['1','2','3'], [1, 2, 3])
```

in matplotlib 1.4.3, it shows
[image]

in matplotlib 2.1.1, it shows

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue on matplotlib 2.2.2. Try upgrading?

Comment: @nicoco: Same here for 2.2.0. Runs as it should.

Comment: Honestly I think it should have thrown, I find this quite fishy usage...

Comment: With matplotlib 2.2.2, the result look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwqka.png). So is the question why there is a bug in 2.1.1? The answer is probably, that the categorical plotting (i.e. string plotting) has been freshly introduced in 2.1.0 and new features are always susceptible to bugs, which will then be removed in some later version.

Comment: I have upgraded it to version 2.2.3, it works normally now.